# Unable to load the requested file: content/_assets/glossary_items.php after upgrade

Tags: matrix, ee1, ee2-upgrades, bug

Just upgraded a site from 1.6.6 to 2.5.5 and when I went to edit an entry or publish a new entry I got

```
Unable to load the requested file: content/_assets/glossary_items.php
```

From initial digging on EE forums, they all pointed toward Matrix being the issue, however this site had ZERO add-ons.

I installed Matrix and the issue is now non-existent. Having Matrix installed isn't really a solution.

Comment: Steven, did you ever have Matrix installed? Also, did you traverse to that directory in the filesystem and see if that actually exists? I'm wondering if there may have been some file transfer failures when uploading those files.

Comment: no, Matrix was never installed - the site had never used any add-ons. This was an EE 1.6.6 site upgraded to 2.5.5 The file exists and has content within that looks OK. I tried copying the files across again (I did the upgrade locally). As I said, I don't think this is a Matrix issue.

Comment: I know, I was just hoping to help you figure it out, even if Matrix isn't at fault. :)  Unfortunately I don't have other ideas on what may be going on, especially if the file is actually there.  Does it have more than 0 bytes and proper permissions?

Comment: yup - it's a weird one all right.

Comment: Just a thought, that maybe the site _once_ had an add-on...though where the call for it could be seems a mystery, unless it's lying around in config.php or database. Maybe you could do some searching through an sql export of the database, beyond config itself?

Comment: nope, no add-on at any point in history, a EE site as pure as the driven snow.

Comment: I just set up a completely fresh EE 2.8.1 install and I'm getting the exact same error when trying to access the publish page. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason I never really got to the bottom of this.

However, installing Matrix and then removing it did the trick for us.

Comment: just came across this weird bug again upgrading an EE 1.5.0 site. The same thing worked again, installed Matrix, then removed it. Weird as.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this on a fresh EE install. Kinda weird, but thanks for the tip. Installing matrix worked for me as well.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.